# Woocommerce save custom field to order meta key

Tags: woocommerce, metadata, checkout

I have a Woocommerce shop where users can book to hire a waste skip.

I needed a custom date picker field at the top of the checkout, so I used a plugin to create a custom date picker field at the top of the checkout within the billing fields.

When a waste skip is booked, the order is saved in Woocommerce, but we also have a third party plugin that sends the order through an API to back office software.

The problem is the delivery date (The new date picker field) is not sending the date to the third party, it is just saving it to the Woocommerce order.

**This is the field I have added**
[new datepicker field setting in plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYwyH.png)

**The third party API states this:**
Delivery date is a required field by our API.
Please make sure you map your custom delivery date to "_wlogics_delivery_date" (order meta)

I have tried to hook into the following:
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'save_order_custom_meta_data');

```
function save_order_custom_meta_data( $order_id ) {
        
if ( ! empty( $_POST['billing_wlogics_delivery_date'] ) ) {
 update_post_meta( $order_id, 'wlogics_date_field', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_wlogics_delivery_date'] ) );
}

}
```

What I am trying to do here is grab the custom date picker field and update the order meta field wlogics_date_field but it never works and I don't know why.